# Loaded objects altered by render() with multiple views?

Tags: xtk

I'm still in my attempt to visualize a scene with 3 views (one full interactive, one from right with only zoom, one from top with only zoom, see here : [Change the 'config' attribute of an interactor for disabling some user events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380269/change-the-config-attribute-of-an-interactor-for-disabling-some-user-events)).

The handling of user events is ok. I tried 2 options for loading the object in the 3 renderers: the stupid one and the one of lesson 07. The commented code is optionnal to see the issue (it's to have the view from right or top with only the zoom).

Option 1 : lesson 07

```
var run = function() {

var r1 = new X.renderer('r1');
r1.init();

var r2 = new X.renderer('r2');
r2.init();
r2.interactor().config.MOUSECLICKS_ENABLED = false;
r2.interactor().config.KEYBOARD_ENABLED = false;
r2.interactor().config.HOVERING_ENABLED = false;
r2.interactor().config.CONTEXTMENU_ENABLED = false;
r2.interactor().init();

var r3 = new X.renderer('r3');
r3.init();
//r3.interactor().config.MOUSECLICKS_ENABLED = false;
//r3.interactor().config.KEYBOARD_ENABLED = false;
//r3.interactor().config.HOVERING_ENABLED = false;
//r3.interactor().config.CONTEXTMENU_ENABLED = false;
//r3.interactor().init();

var objet= new X.object(); //typo corrected
objet.load('monobjet.stl');
r1.add(objet);

r1.onShowtime = function() {
    r2.add(objet);
    r3.add(objet);
    //r2.camera().setPosition(100,0,0);
    //r3.camera().setPosition(0,100,0);     
    r2.render();
    r3.render();
};  
r1.render();
```

Option 2 : stupid

```
var run = function() {

var r1 = new X.renderer('r1');
r1.init();

var r2 = new X.renderer('r2');
r2.init();
r2.interactor().config.MOUSECLICKS_ENABLED = false;
r2.interactor().config.KEYBOARD_ENABLED = false;
r2.interactor().config.HOVERING_ENABLED = false;
r2.interactor().config.CONTEXTMENU_ENABLED = false;
r2.interactor().init();

var r3 = new X.renderer('r3');
r3.init();
//r3.interactor().config.MOUSECLICKS_ENABLED = false;
//r3.interactor().config.KEYBOARD_ENABLED = false;
//r3.interactor().config.HOVERING_ENABLED = false;
//r3.interactor().config.CONTEXTMENU_ENABLED = false;
//r3.interactor().init();

var objet= new X.object(); //typo corrected
objet.load('monobjet.stl');
r1.add(objet);
r2.add(objet);
r3.add(objet);
//r2.camera().setPosition(100,0,0);
//r3.camera().setPosition(0,100,0);
r1.render();        
r2.render();
r3.render();
};
```

The stupid option gives black screens for r2 and r3, the one of lesson 07 gives my objects in the 3 renderers, but it's has moved in r2 and r3 (you will also see it in lesson 7 if you comment the setPosition() or look meticulously). Furthermore, if i use the mouse to rotate the view, I see than my object is not centered on 0 in r2 but not in r2 nor r3.

So my question is : do r1.render() alterate my "object"'s buffers ? Is it expected ? I've looked on Stack Overflow and Github for similar questions but seen nothing.

I also tried with a X.cube in addition to see better (by var object2 = new X.cube(...)) and it was the same.

---

I think I found the issue with 1 test : when i add object.points().setClean() before adding it to the first renderer, it is not centered on the object like the other ones.

So it seeems the issue us the following :
When you add an object loaded from a file for the first time its "points" are dirty and at the following times they are clean. So the issue comes from "points.setClean();" in renderer.update_() in the block where the vertexBuffer is recomputed no ? Is that normal ?

If I well understand :
- the 1st renderer sees the points are dirty and so compute a new boudning box to fit the object within the center of the view, and then when he sees the object is new he computes a new vertexBuffer et cleans the object.points attribute.
- the other renderers see the points are not dirty anymore so they don't compute a boudning box, but they see object is new so they compute the buffer.

What could be a solution ? I must change the "if (points.dirty() || transform.dirty())" in renderer.update_() or make it true for the following renderers ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
var machoire = new X.object();
objet.load('monobjet.stl');
r1.add(objet);
r2.add(objet);
r3.add(objet);
```

Is it just a typo? Should be

```
var objet = new X.object();
objet.load('monobjet.stl');
```

I think version 1 from above should work.

Comment: Yes just a typo (error in rewriting my code), but it wasn't here in my test version.

Comment: Here (http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/8779/testmultiscreenload.png) is the result with the version 1 and a simple mesh. You can see in renderers 2 & 3 the image isn't positioned the same way. It is not a disturbance in that simple case, but with bigger objects it happens that the object is out of view when the renderers start.

Comment: After a few more tests (setting the cameras positions and focus, setting view from a render's camera to another, ...) it seems that it is not the camera that is the problem. I also tried to copy "objet" and add this copy instead of the original to r3, and added cubes to see better the difference, it gave me it : http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/8779/testmultiscreenload.png.

Comment: Could it come from the lines 1238 to 1277 of X/vizualisation/renderer.js, in the method X.renderer.prototype.update_() ? And the action on "objet"'s transform attribute ? I think so but my understanding of xtk is far from perfect, and because adding a cube updates and this changes my result too (renderers which were the sames before aren't anymore).

Comment: I see! Try to do the following: 1) use r.resetBoundingBox() on the renderers in the onShowtime function - also if you have live versions I can play around with it.

Comment: I tried to copy cameras and reset view/render/BB of the renderers on sow time, it had no effect. What surprises me the most is with it, rotation (for examples) doesn't look like to be done around the same axis. I'll try to make some live code presentable !

Comment: the rotations are global right now.. so when the bounding box is not recalculated, the scene is not centered to 0,0,0 and the rotation won't be around the objects own axis. So reset bounding box and maybe a object.modified() call should fix it?